# How to fire a SPGridView RowDataBound Event?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, event-handling

In web user control in `asp.net` i am using one `spgridview`.
I want to fire `spgridview_rowdataevent`. How can i do it?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your GridView

```
OnRowDataBound="GridViewRowEventHandler"
```

and then in your code behind do what ever you want using

```
void GridViewRowEventHandler(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

Comment: My gridview is sharepoint gridview. In this gridview i want to hide my footer row.how can i do it?

Comment: If your grid is SPGridView And you want to hide your footer row the copy and paste this code it will work. I am using it.
Add this code to your aspx in SPGridView


      OnDataBound="SPGridView1_RowDataBound"


Add this line to your VB.Net page


     Protected Sub SPGridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me.SPGridView1.BottomPagerRow.Visible = False
    End Sub